# How to avoid Collection Error Python Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to train a Linear Regression Qualifier to continue a grap.
I have a couple of thousand lines of data in my csv file that I import into numpy arrays. Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import csv
import math
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def predict():
    sample_data = pd.read_csv("includes\\csv.csv")
    x = np.array(sample_data["day"])
    y = np.array(sample_data["balance"])

    for x in x:
        x = x.reshape(1, -1)
        #lol

    for y in y:
        y.reshape(1, -1)
        #lol

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    clf.score(x_test, y_test)
```

When I run this, the error is:

```
TypeError: Singleton array 6014651 cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

Any ideas why that's a thing?

Comment: You could provide a broader stacktrace, especially in which line the error occurs, but I would point at the loops with reshape: first, I would not say that iterator of the same name as the collection being iterated is a good idea. Second, why not reshape whole array? Like `x =x.reshape(-1,1)`, without the `for` loop

Comment: In which line does the error happen? Is this really the shortest possible [example]? You can try to localize the problem by throwing out all the stuff that is not needed, also in the processed data.

Comment: the error occurs in the line "X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)"

Comment: could you try change the loops to `for xi in x: xi = xi.reshape(1, -1)` and similarly for y? But again, I would recommend reshaping whole array, not each row separately.

Comment: any sample input

Comment: So I tried to make the file by hand, and 1) changing iterators' names, as in previous comment, worked. 2) in two last lines you have `x_train` and `x_test` - they should start with capital X, as you declared them. 3) You want classifier (not qualifier btw) or regressor? If you want classifier, you probably should call Logistic Regression instead of Linear Regression, which is a regressor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion in comments:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import csv
import math
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def predict():
    sample_data = pd.read_csv("includes\\csv.csv")
    x = np.array(sample_data["day"])
    y = np.array(sample_data["balance"])

    x = x.reshape(-1,1)

    y = y.reshape(-1,1)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

X_train, X_test should be capitals, python variables are case sensitive